# Access method from Viewcontroller when embedded in navigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have two View controllers AVC and BVC , I'm presenting modally BVC with a CustomTransition animation. I need to access a method "myMethod()" from
AVC.
This is the part of the code where the problem is:

```
enum TransitionType {

case presentation

case dismissal

}


class CustomTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

var transition: TransitionType = .presentation



func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {


    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)

    let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)




    // When AVC is embedded in navigationController, I can't access  "myMethod"

    guard let myObject = transition == .presentation ? (fromVC as! AVC).myMethod() : (toVC as! AVC).myMethod() else { return }

    myObject.isHidden = true

    etc...
```

Everything is working great as it is but when I embedded AVC in a navigationController this dosen't work anymore.
What can I do to make it work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fromVC` is now a `UINavigationController` rather than AVC. To access the latter,  you need to retrieve it using `navigationController?.viewControllers.first`. This, however, assumes that AVC is the first view controller embedded in the `navigationController` object.

Comment: Hello,
And thank you for your answer. I guess you are right but when I try to access it with navigationController?.viewControllers it tells me "Use of unresolved identifier 'navigationController'"